# JPA One-to-Many relationship when join column is not the Primary Key from the first (one) table

Tags: spring, jpa, one-to-many

So here is my first table **Entity1**:

[image]

And my second table **Entity2**:

[image]

So Entity1 has many Entity2 but this relationship is enforced by the **foo_id** column. It is not enforced by the PK of Entity1. As you can see Entity2 does not have an **entity1_id** FK column.

I can't modify the Entity2 table to include the entity1_id. I understand that If I could do that (but again I can't) it would be easy to specify the @OneToMany JPA relationship.

So what do I do here to create my @OneToMany relationship with JPA?

Comment: "With JPA" ? The *only* way to create it "with JPA" is to create a proper relationship in your class (which you say you can't do). So you are left to MANUALLY manage this integer nonsense yourself.